# how to show shiny groupcheckbox choices into specific number of rows and columns

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny

I want the choices of this groupcheckbox to be shown into 4 columns. Like 1,2 in one column- 3,4 in the 2nd column and so on. I am new to shiny dashboard, so any hint is highly appreciated.

```
checkboxGroupInput("myGroup",
 label ="",
 width="100px",
 inline=TRUE,
 choices = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
 selected = c(1,8))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to changes in order to make it happend:

1. You choices, created in a different order
2. Use css to make the columns (or rows), with css grid

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput(
    "myGroup",
    label ="",
    width = "200px",
    inline=TRUE,
    choices = c(seq(1, 7, 2), seq(2, 8, 2)),
    selected = c(1,8)),
  tags$style(
    "#myGroup .shiny-options-group {display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;}
    .checkbox-inline{margin: 0 !important}")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]